# Need use PHP to read directory directly not layer by layer

Tags: php, opendir

I need to access a remote URL like `\\filesystem\XXX\YYY`. 
And the remote URL manager allows me to access `\\filesystem` and `\\filesystem\XXX\YYY`, while `\\filesystem\XXX` does not.
so `opendir("\\filesystem")` works fine, and `opendir("\\filesystem\XXX\YYY")` return false.
I guess `opendir()` read its path layer by layer, so it returns false when it goes to `\\filesystem\XXX`.
Is there any way to access the URL directly?

---

Here is my situation.
I'm in Department A and there is another department called XXX. They put their documents in `\\filesystem\XXX` and make a directory `YYY` to share some files with other departments.
That's why I have permission to access `\\filesystem` and `\\filesystem\XXX\YYY` ,but not `\\filesystem\XXX`.

---

Thanks for helping me to solve this problem. I called `system("whoami")` to find out that apache is running by a system account without permission to access `\\filesystem\XXX\YYY`.

Comment: Permissionsssss

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky Perhaps I did not express clearly.I have permission to access `\\filesystem` and `\\filesystem\XXX\YYY`,but not `\\filesystem\XXX`. I can open `\\filesystem\XXX\YYY` using windows explorer.

Comment: It does not contradict what @Hanky웃Panky said. You may not have permissions to `/var/www` and still have permissions to `/var/www/sites` for example.

Comment: What permissions do they set on the `YYY` directory that makes it accessible within an inaccessible folder?  Typically permissions are hierarchical, e.g. the child inherits permissions from the parent.

Comment: `layer by layer` is missleading ... say `recursively` or `subdirectories` or `subpaths` instead... ;)